# possibility of using PCL (Euclidean Cluster Extraction) for object detection

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I need to detect objects (1-3) using Kinect at the same time. I did some research but I could not find any package for objects detection in ROS. I want to use depth information as input data and finally calculate distance of objects to camera. For objection detection, do I employ clustering methods? for example, Euclidean Cluster Extraction is provided by PCL so could I use [these codes](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php#cluster-extraction) in a ROS node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202122/possibility-of-using-pcl-(euclidean-cluster-extraction)-for-object-detection/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An object recognition package (which is now slightly outdated, but still working) is [ORK](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/)

You can also use Point Cloud Library (PCL). Our research lab uses PCL, as well as specific feature descriptors, such as CVFH. PCL can sometimes be a pain to work with, but it's quite powerful and has some decent descriptors for object recognition.

Look at these pages for more information:

- [ORK](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/)
- [PCL ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl)
- [general PCL information](http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PhD-3D-Object-Tracking)

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-10-04**:
Is there anyway to find moving objects.... whatever the object is ... could be human or any other thing ? I have a kinect 3d camera and usinf ROS indigo?